# Best strategies for sync when local data is modified multiple times

Tags: android, mobile, local-storage, offline

I've read a lot about regarding offline cache strategies but unfortunately I found nothing that can fulfils my requirements.

Let's say that I have a list of Order in my local database that need to be synced back with the server if one of them is modified. The Order can have multiple statuses like: New, Started, Paused and Completed. The status changes must be synced sequentially with the server because the order is also important.

Creating the table with "isModified" column is not good for me because i need to sync every status change one by one sequentially, not just the last one.

What are the best strategies to store all status changes when the device is offline? I am thinking about duplicating the Order table or creating a new one for the sync data because there can be also other objects not just Orders.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of modifications is relevant, you should store each modification in some kind of ordered data structure, e.g. another local table.

Answer (score 1):

Use Firebase Database for offline database. It synchronises automatically when an internet connection is active.

Add the line below in your `Application` class:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I cannot use google play services in my app and I already have a Room database that I want to use.

Comment: hi @Blehi , do you finally get some strategy ? I need something like what you asked!

Comment: I used another local table as suggested by @F43nd1r in the accepted answer. Every row in the table contains one event to sync. For me the order of the events was also important and I sync every row one by one ordered by ID. Please also note that I store every event as JSON String (to be ready for the sync) but maybe you don't need that.